# Working with linkbutton in the gridview and the output the data to jquery modal form

Tags: datagridview, jquery-dialog, linkbutton

i have a gridview linked with the database. Data in the gridview (username(linkbutton), email, address and postcode). So, what i want is when i click on one of the username, the detail of the user will show up in the jquery modal form. How do i do that?